# Perl Split combined with additional REGEX

Tags: regex, perl, split

My question is two-fold:

Scenario: I am generating a CSV log file that uses a standard comma delimiter.  There are currently four "columns" in the CSV file, but more could be added in the future. I am interested in limiting my REGEX Search/Replace to a specific column of data (e.g., COL 2).

The data in column two varies based on the responding device.  Ultimately, I'm using REGEXs to "condition" the value to a floating number to two decimal places.  Some entries come in with various artifacts (e.g. extra letters or other representations) that I convert to the appropriate floating point representation using REGEX.  All of the REGEXs work well for my purposes right now, but I want to limit these REGEXs to only data in column two (COL 2), so if I add similarly formatted columns (e.g., floating point numbers) in the future they're not effected by the column 2 REGEXs.

One way I thought of doing this is using split and saving column data into into scalar variables, then running the COL2 scalar through a loop or sub-routine containing the REGEXs and then re-writing the conditioned COL2 value back out to a new CSV file. (I'm currently doing this with Perl's $^I variable.)

```
$^I = ".org";

while (<>) { 
  my ($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4) = (split /,/);
  $col2 =~ s/EXP1/FORMATTED/;
  $col2 =~ s/EXP2/FORMATTED/;
  $col2 =~ s/EXP3/FORMATTED/;

  my $new_rec = join ",", $col1,$col2,$col3,$col4;

  print $new_rec;
}
```

So Question 1: I'm wondering if this is efficient enough or if I'm doing unnecessary work?  Can I add the commas in the REGEX specifically such that it only works against COL2?

Question 2: In response to a question re: split ([SPLIT Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598490/how-can-i-extract-a-value-from-comma-separated-values-in-perl)), brian d foy says the following regarding Text::CSV_XS: "It's extremely fast, which is why I said "extremely optimized". Read its docs. It also handles CSV correctly, which split doesn't."

If this is accurate, meaning split doesn't correctly handle CSV files, will my above solution work over time?  I'm not sure what he means by split doesn't handle CSV correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where your data comes from. If you are *certain* that the fields will never be in quotes then `split` is fine, and is the best solution.

Here is how I would write your code. The `for` loop temporarily aliases `$_` to `$fields[1]` for the extent of the block, and allows you to manipulate the value without expressly mentioning the variable. The output is sent to `STDOUT`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  chomp;

  my @fields = split /,/;
  for ($fields[1]) {
    s/EXP1/FORMATTED/;
    s/EXP2/FORMATTED/;
    s/EXP3/FORMATTED/;
  }

  print join(',', @fields), "\n";
}
```

Comment: this answers my original question. As you mention, I am guaranteed that the second column will never be in quotes, nor contain an in-field comma.  I like the use of $_ to access the `@fields` array, this is a clean way to focus only on my column of interest.  I did have a secondary question about your solution...if each line of the CSV file ends with a newline character, I can potentially just not chomp the line and forgo appending the newline to the join statement, correct?  That said, it's probably better coding practice to chomp and re-add the newline.  Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing what [toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197758/toolic) mentioned, it's risky to just `split` CSV data, since you may erringly `split` a column value.  Given this, here's a [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.02/CSV_XS.pm) option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new( { binary => 1, auto_diag => 1 } )
  or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();
my $sepChar = $csv->sep_char();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", $ARGV[0] or die "$ARGV[0]: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    $row->[2] =~ s/this/that/;
    print join ',', map { /$sepChar/ ? qq{"$_"} : $_ } @$row;
}

$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
```

Command-line usage: `>perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Note that you can do all of your s/// on col 2.  The `map` includes a check for a separator character (usually a comma) in the array element.  If one exists, the element's enclosed in double quotes--to maintain the CSV formatting.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Since you're certain there are no commas in your CSV fields, you really don't need to `split` the data, do the substitutions, reassemble the data, and then `print` it.  You can set up a hash whose key/value pairs are the match/substitute pairs used in substitutions.  Then, just use a regex to capture the col2 value for a substitution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = ( 1 => '1.00', 'unk' => '0.00' );

while (<DATA>) {
    s/^(?:.+?,)\K([^,]+)/exists $hash{$1} ?  $hash{$1} : $1/e;
    print;
}

__DATA__
12345,1,342,789.0
47.42,unk,17.6,12
17,34,12.5,0
```

Output:

```
12345,1.00,342,789.0
47.42,0.00,17.6,12
17,34,12.5,0
```

Comment: @toolic and Kenosis, the potential unwanted split of a CSV cell using split makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying.  Regarding the use of [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.02/CSV_XS.pm) The example above should work well.  Assuming `$row[2] is actually $row[1] (second element in row)` and that multiple REGEXs can appear inline against the same variable... `$row[1]-> =~ s/1/1.00/;` and `$row[1]-> =~ s/unk/0.00/;` etc...  Is that correct?

Comment: @user3000685 - You're most welcome!  Yes, `$row->[1]` denotes accessing the second array element.  Please review [Borodin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)'s excellent answer.  I didn't mean to make it seem *categorically* bad to `split` CSV data.

Comment: thanks again for the response.  I will undoubtedly use this technique in the future.  There's a lot of powerful Perl in use here.  In this particular case, Borodin's solution is more applicable, as I do not have to worry about accommodating extra quoted commas within the field I'm evaluating. Nevertheless, I learned something new from you as well. thanks.

Comment: @user3000685 - You're most welcome!  It is certainly good to choose the best code for the task at hand.

Comment: @user3000685 - Have provided another solution for substitutions in your comma-free CSV values.

Comment: +3; Wow, this definitely adds to the TMTOWTDI motto of Perl! If I'm following the REGEX, it says: perform a non-capturing match of the first column(denoted by an ending comma `^(?:.+?,)`, then using `\K` start a clean search and capture any characters proceeding the next comma (i.e., anything that's not a comma `[^,]`) and capture into `$1`, which defaults us to the second column of data.  Then using the Ternary operator and exists hash functions, check the hash for predefined replacements. Is this correct? Will the `([^,]+)` capture everything but a comma, OR should I add a `.` -> `([.^,]+)`?

Comment: @user3000685 - Well done!  You've *captured* the code's meaning!  Think `\K`eep all to the left. The `([^,]+)` is sufficient to effectively capture everything that's not a comma.  If you're processing a lot of lines, you'll likely notice that this is much faster than using `split` and `join`  The downside is that it may not be as *readable*, i.e., "What's going on here?"--unless it's commented.  However, you do have a handle on it.

Comment: that's great. I do have 80K lines, so this will be a lot faster for me.  I like the use of the `\K` and the lazy `?` on the `,` -- it essentially creates a word boundary function using commas for the column of interest.  Thank you!